# gulp.js file does not work with browserify and reactify

Tags: gulp, browserify

The following gulp.js file runs without error but does not output a bundle.js - at command line we run node gulp.js   the console.log msgs inside task do not show but the others do thks for any help

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var browserify = require("browserify");
var reactify = require("reactify");
var source = require("vinyl-source-stream");

console.log("read in requires");

gulp.task("scripts", function() {
  console.log("task");
  var bundler = browserify ({
    entries: ["./app.js"],
    transform: [reactify],
    debug: true
  });

  var bundle = function() {
    console.log("bundle");
    return bundler
      .bundle()
      .pipe(source("bundle.js"))
      .pipe(buffer())
      .pipe(gulp.dest("./build"));
  };
  return bundle();
});
console.log("done");
```

Comment: Why do you expect that running `node gulp.js` would execute that task? File should be called `gulpfile.js` and task will run by `gulp scripts`.

Comment: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md

Comment: thks for feedback - we have now created a proper gulpfile.js following a posted script for vinyl-transform BUT now a simple react file will not run => react not found